# scaling view dynamically

Tags: android, android-widget

Hi i want to display 4 frames in layout which contains customized views.when ever i clicked on one frame it has to occupy total screen. please let me know how to do .

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height of the view dynamically, you have to hide the other views before making the clicked view to display full screen.

Comment: i have two views in linearlayout. when i clicked on the second view it should expand from 0,0 but it not .can u let me know how to do it.

Comment: You may have to use AbsoluteLayout but it is deprecated now

Comment: You can also call onLayout() method on the view which takes left, top, width and height as params.

Comment: But i have to display 4 windows which will look exactly like the one in windows os. each one have some data to display and having minimize and maximize button.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps, you could try adding activities for each different screen you need, right?